# Read & extract data from xml file using sql query

Tags: c#, sql, xml

We have dozen of xml files built with same structure and we need to extract some nodes. my question here is it good practice to use sql server to extract data from xml or is it better to use c# programming. which one is better  in terms of speed and performance( using sql query or using c#)

Thanks

Comment: sql is better if you want to save it directly to database...

Comment: I can't comment on speed or performance (which is why I'm only leaving a comment any not an answer) but in that situation I'd go about trying to query the XML using LINQ if only because it cuts out a whole step (importing into SQL Server.) This is of course only if you don't want the data in the database apart from being able to query it.

Comment: Thank you guys for your response, it is really help, i was thinking to use linq as it is good and faster way , but it is company requirement unless i can justify why linq is better. Thanks again